# Polynomial curve fitting with a set of points plus an angle constraint

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm trying to find the polynomial equation of degree 3 passing through a set of given points as explained in this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting).

However, instead of providing 4 points, I'd like to provide 3 points plus an angle constraint for the middle point.

Finding the matrix for the given set of points it pretty straightforward and explained in the article but I'm not sure how to express the angle constraint in the matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angle constraint is really a constraint for the derivative. So if your polynomial $f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ shall pass through $(x_0,y_0)$ at angle $\alpha$, then you get (using the fact that $f'(x)=3ax^2+2bx+c$) the constraint
$$ ax_0^3+bx_0^2+cx_0+d=y_0$$
from the point itself
and
$$ 3ax_0^2+2bx_0+c=\tan\alpha$$
from the slope at that point.

Comment: Thanks, but isn't it $f'\left( x \right)=3ax^{2}+2bx+c$ and I don't get why it's $4ax_{0}^{2}$ and not $3ax_{0}^{2}$ for the slope at the point.

Comment: I think the answer has a couple of typos. The derivative function should be $f'(x)=3ax^2+2bx+c$, and the equation obtained from the derivative function should be $3ax_0^2+2bx_0+c=\tan\alpha$.